# ZeroMQ Clone Server Model 1

Tags: c, zeromq

I'm new to ZeroMQ and am trying to understand the library by running the sample examples in C.

Currently I'm working on the Clone Server Model 1 example in C from chapter 5 of the ZeroMQ documentation. I have copied the client and server code here. I have modified the programs to account for the deprecation of the class **`zctx`**. I'm using `zsock.h` instead. Didn't include the file **`kvsimple.c`** for brevity.

Whenever I run the program ( client first and then the server ), the client always enters the `if(){...}` code-section and breaks, printing the Interrupted message. I don't understand why this is the case. Original code using `zctx` can be found at [**client**](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:clonecli1) and [**server**](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:clonesrv1).

Modified client code:

```
#include "kvsimple.h"
int main (void) {
    // Prepare our context and updates socket
    // zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
    zsock_t *updates = zsock_new (ZMQ_SUB);
    zsock_set_subscribe (updates, "");
    zsock_connect (updates, "tcp://localhost:5556");

    zhash_t *kvmap = zhash_new ();
    int64_t sequence = 0;

    while (true) {
        kvmsg_t *kvmsg = kvmsg_recv (updates);
        if (!kvmsg) 
            break;          //  Interrupted
        kvmsg_store (&kvmsg, kvmap);
        sequence++;
    }
    printf (" Interrupted\n%d messages in\n", (int) sequence);
    zhash_destroy (&kvmap);
    zsock_destroy (&updates);
    return 0;
}
```

Modified server code

```
#include "kvsimple.h"
int main (void) {
    // Prepare our context and publisher socket
    // zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
    zsock_t *publisher = zsock_new (ZMQ_PUB);
    zsock_bind (publisher, "tcp://*:5556");
    zclock_sleep (200);

    zhash_t *kvmap = zhash_new ();
    int64_t sequence = 0;
    srandom ((unsigned) time (NULL));

    while (true) { 
        //  Distribute as key-value message
        kvmsg_t *kvmsg = kvmsg_new (++sequence);
        kvmsg_fmt_key  (kvmsg, "%d", randof (10000));
        kvmsg_fmt_body (kvmsg, "%d", randof (1000000));
        kvmsg_send     (kvmsg, publisher);
        kvmsg_store   (&kvmsg, kvmap);
    }
    printf (" Interrupted\n%d messages out\n", (int) sequence);
    zhash_destroy (&kvmap);
    zsock_destroy (&publisher);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: kvsimple.c is available at http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:kvsimple

Comment: What changes did you do to kvsimple.c? In the original, `zmq_msg_recv` is used in `kvmsg_recv`(c.f. https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/kvmsg.c#L148). Since `czmq`now uses `zsock_t` instead of the bare zmq socket handle, this will no longer work.